# How to sync namespace from author to publish using code in AEM 6.2

Tags: aem

While activating some document to publish server, it is getting stuck in replication queue. by checking log found that some namespace is missing from publish server. After adding namespace through crx/explorer, replication through.(It is mandatory have namespace on both servers otherwise, replication will fail.)

Where as if a namespace is missing for some random document (especially PDF) replication is getting stuck/failed.

Before Oak (AEM 6.0), to sync namespace from author to publish, one can create a package from author and upload to publish server. However, after 6.0 it is not allowed uploading package for namespace. **Is there any way to synchronize author's namespace to publish's namespace for AEM 6+ ?**

Comment: How are you creating your namespace on author?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to synchronize author's namespace to publish's namespace for AEM 6+ ?

**TL;DR**

Yes, Replication supports it OOTB for CQ 5.x and AEM 6.x. Make sure the user which does install the replication packages is granted the repository level `jcr:namespaceManagement` privilege which allows managing the name spaces.

**Long version**

Yes, there are two ways. Either let the replication automatically create the required namespaces or pre-install the namespaces.

### Replication auto-creating required namespaces

Namespaces are implicitly carried in the Durbo replication packages. Replication does automatically create missing namespaces in the target instance as part of installing Durbo packages. This is the OOTB behaviour for CQ 5.x and AEM 6.x.

The user installing the Durbo packages must have sufficient privilege in order to be able to create the missing namespaces. This user can be defined via the configuration as documented in [Replication > Transport > User](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/configuring/replication.html#contentbody_procedure_6). This user will need to be granted the Namespace Management privilege.

#### Granting Namespace Management privilege

You can use CRX/DE for granting repository level privileges.

1. Login to CRX/DE as admin
2. Click on Access Control tab
3. Click on Repository
4. Add an Access Control Entry

[image]

5. Set the name of the user to grant privilege
6. Check the `jcr:namespaceManagement` privilege
7. Click on OK

[image]

#### Symptom of bad configuration

The replication queue is blocked and stack traces similar to the following are logged

```
Caused by: javax.jcr.AccessDeniedException: Failed to register namespace mapping test1 -> http://localhost/test/1.0
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException.asRepositoryException(CommitFailedException.java:231)
    ...
    at com.day.cq.replication.impl.content.durbo.DurboImporter.createNode(DurboImporter.java:286)
    ... 108 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException: OakAccess0000: Access denied
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.security.authorization.permission.PermissionValidator.checkPermissions(PermissionValidator.java:242)
    ...
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.name.ReadWriteNamespaceRegistry.registerNamespace(ReadWriteNamespaceRegistry.java:94)
    ... 113 common frames omitted
```

This is clear sign that the replication user is missing `jcr:namespaceManagement` privilege.

### Manually synchronise namespaces

This works with CQ 5.x and AEM 6.x and leverage the Package Manager.

In order to transfer the new namespace, you need to create a new content package on the source instance, using the Package Manager. The package will need to include either:

1. a node which has a property referencing the new namespace
2. a `.cnd` file containing the definition of the namespace

Then you'd need to download the content package and install it in the target instance while being logged in with a user that is granted the repository level `jcr:namespaceManagement` privilege.

Comment: I know that its a 3+ year old answer, but where would someone find the .cnd file containing the namespace definition?